# Context Free Grammer (CFG) for a language

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language

Consider the language above $\Sigma = \{a,b,\$\}$:
$$L = \left\{ x$y : x,y\in\{a,b\}^* \land \left|x\right| \ne \left|y\right| \right\}$$

I need define a CFG for this language. I've tried couple of CFGs but they all failed in one way or another.

I'd be glad for help.

Comment: I assume $|x|$ means the length of string $x$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: With $S$ as the initial symbol, start with these productions:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to aL\mid bL\mid Ra\mid Rb\\
&L\to aL\mid bL\mid X
\end{align*}$$

Have $R$ do something similar to what $L$ does, and have $X$ generate the language

$$\big\{x\#y:x,y\in\{a,b\}^*\land |x|=|y|\big\}\;.$$

In other words, generate excess length on one side, then generate equal lengths on both sides from that point on.

Comment: @Elimination: You’re welcome!